# What is the "System" disk that shows up in Disk Defragmenter?

Tags: windows, defragment

When I run the "Disk Defragmenter" program that is included with Windows, two different "drives" show up. The first is, as expected, my `C:` drive. The second just shows up as `System`:

[image: Disk Defragmenter "System" disk]

What is this `System` disk that shows up?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is only one partition on that computer, but in a few hours I'll be able to confirm that from a Linux LiveCD.

Comment: It's the System partition. It's used by Windows and is not shown in Windows Explorer, neither does it have a drive letter.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hidden partition used internally by Windows to store files related to the Boot Manager & Boot Configuration Database and BitLocker Drive Encryption.

More information is available at [this Microsoft TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg441289.aspx):

> If you install Windows 7 on a clean disk with no existing partitions,
>   it creates a System Reserved partition at the beginning of the disk
>   and uses the remainder of the unallocated space to create your system
>   drive.That small partition isn’t assigned a drive letter, so you won’t
>   even know it exists unless you look in the Disk Management console or
>   use a low-level utility, such as Diskpart, to inspect the disk
>   structure.
>
> [image]
>
> This “stub” of a partition, which is new in Windows 7, serves two
>   functions. First, it holds the Boot Manager code and the Boot
>   Configuration Database. Second, it reserves space for the startup
>   files required by the BitLocker Drive Encryption feature. If you ever
>   decide to encrypt your system drive using BitLocker, you won’t have to
>   repartition your system drive to make it possible.
>
> If you’re confident you’ll never use BitLocker and prefer to do
>   without the additional complexity of this System Reserved partition,
>   your best bet is to make sure it’s never created. For a truly clean
>   installation starting from an unformatted hard drive, you must use a
>   different disk-management utility, such as the setup disk available
>   from many hard-disk manufacturers or a startup disk from Windows
>   Vista. Create a single primary partition using all unallocated space,
>   and then point the installer to the newly created partition as the
>   setup location. (Note that you cannot use the graphical
>   disk-management tools available from the Windows 7 DVD to perform this
>   task.) After you use the alternative tool to create a partition on the
>   drive, you can point the Windows 7 installer to that location and it
>   will proceed.
>
> If you’re comfortable with command-line disk management tools, you
>   can use the Diskpart utility from the setup program to create the
>   necessary partition. At the beginning of setup, before you select the
>   location where you want to install Windows:
>
> 1. Press Shift+F10 to open
>      a Command Prompt window
> 2. Type diskpart to enter the Diskpart environment
> 3. Assuming you have a single clean hard disk, use select disk 0 and create partition primary to manually create a new partition
> 4. Proceed with the Windows 7 setup, using this new partition as the setup location

Answer (score 0):

This is the [System reserved partition where the Windows Bootloder is stored](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg441289.aspx). Normally that partition is hidden and has no letter assigned.